# grep with regular expression to find two words when word b is AFTER word a in a sentence

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, grep

I have a big text file, each line containing a sentence.
I want to use grep (or something similar in batch) to find sentences where word b occurs exactly or not exactly (some word(s) between them) after word a.

I don't want grep to return a sentence like this:

```
f g s b d a
```

because b is not after a but I want to return a sentence like

```
f g a d m s b f
```

because b is after a.

It is OK to return sentences where a is both after and before b:

```
s a s b s a s
```

I also don't want sentences with only a or b.

I just want the sentences where b is after a (something can be in the middle).

I can easily do it with Python but I want to use the beauty of bash.

Comment: Define "a sentence".

Comment: assuming you used a reg-ex in python? The same one should work with `grep` and the appropriate options. Good luck.

Comment: a sentence is a line consisting of words.

Comment: I used '\*a\*b\*' for grep, didn't return anything. @shellter.

Comment: I"m surprised that worked, but you're very close. try `grep '.*a.*b' file` . Good luck.

Comment: It didn't work @shellter.

Comment: it worked for me given your sample data above. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, it worked @shellter, thanks.. Both '.*a.*b' and 'a.*b' work great.

Comment: `grep -P 'a(?=.*b)'` should also work. But why to think too much when simple regex can do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do that:

```
grep "a.*b" file
```

Comment: anything can happen before a and after b.

Comment: Sure, @Afshin. So the command above are able to select "f g a d m s b f" for example.

Comment: `egrep` is deprecated in favor of `grep -E` but no need for either, just plain old `grep` will do it. Also the OP didn't say anything about needing/wanting a space after `a` so no reason to put one in the answer. Just use `grep 'a.*b' file`.

Comment: yeah, there might not be a space there.